# So i installed numpy . But when i call it in a program an error occurs. Any method to solve it permanently in windows 10

Tags: python, numpy

Here is the error

```
import numpy

Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'numpy'
  File "C:\path\to\file\32.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me know how did you install the NumPy package; using `pip` or something else?
If you have multiple python versions, i.e. 2.x and 3.x at the same time, please make sure your interpreter for the 32.py file is the version that you installed NumPy on.

Comment: I only have installed python 3.8 . and i installed numpy using pip

Comment: Refer to the answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61128128/7932028
It seems to be your solution

Answer (score 0):

To possibly fix your problem, you should first try installing it and see if there are any errors. You should also check the version of Python you are running on Windows 10, because when you update Python it sometimes switches names between `py` and `python`
[image]

As you can see, the version of Python has changed between `py` and `python` so you should try changing that first.

If this does not work, you should try finding the directory for NumPy and adding it to the system PATH in your script. The installer usually shows you the location by doing the following:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("<insert numpy location here>")
import NumPy
```

This should manually force it into finding the package. If none of this works, please tell us and we should be able to find a different solution.

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a code editor like PyCharm, you could install it by clicking on 
file then settings then the project interpreter setting and install new module! You can search for the module and install.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the python version that you want to use is a Windows Environmental Variable. You can test this by running this line in your command line.

```
> python --version
```

If you get some other python version that is not the one that you wish to use you can set the python version you want by finding where exactly your Python folder is located and go into settings and set the path as a new variable (I can leave a tutorial for you). If that is too much of a hassle, the Python installers can set the python that you will install as an environmental variable for you. (You could uninstall and reinstall and make sure that you allow it to make it an environmental variable.

After that you should be able to import whatever external packages you want using `pip`
for example:

`pip install numpy`